# Need help understanding what is wrong with my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

```
function luminosity(solar_units){
    var solar = solar_units * (3.846*10**26);
    var sunMass = (1.989*10**30);
    var sunLuminosity = (3.846*10**26);
    var mass;

if (solar > (10**-5) || solar < (10**5)) {
    mass = ((sunMass)((1/1.5)**(1/3.5))((solar/sunLuminosity)**(1/3.5)));
    return mass;
};

}

console.log(luminosity(1));
```

The error I get back is:

VM108:8 Uncaught TypeError: sunMass is not a function
at luminosity (:8:20)
at :14:13

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have a set of parens after `sunMass`, which will be interpreted as the function call operator. Did you mean to perform multiplication there?

Comment: You're missing a `*`. Please *read the error* before asking here.

Comment: Multiplication is not implicit in programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line : `mass = ((sunMass)((1/1.5)**(1/3.5))((solar/sunLuminosity)**(1/3.5)));` after`(sunMass)` and also after `((1/1.5)**(1/3.5))` there is no operator. that's why you get the error.

if you add a operator that needed for your formula, it gonna work, for example if you change it to this : `mass = ((sunMass)*((1/1.5)**(1/3.5))*((solar/sunLuminosity)**(1/3.5)));`

you will get this as a result : `1.7714259188419855e+30`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!